# Counting values Var1="A" for the highest Var2 in SQLite3

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a list of games that were played in my database. Every game has a `time` and `result` variable. The result can either be "A wins", "B wins" or "draw".

I want to count the amount of times that "A wins" happens in the last 50 games (the games with the highest time).

At the moment I was thinking of running:

```
 SELECT result FROM games ORDER BY time DESC Limit 50
```

And afterwards going through the list and counting the amount of "A wins". I however feel like it should be possible to everything in SQL but I don't know how. Is there a way to form the query to do everything in SQL?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest to try with two queries. 
First one will fetch a list of last 50 games.
Second query will use results from the first one to count number of games that were won by 'A'.
Those two queries can be composed together as a query with subquery like this

```
select count(result) from
    (
        select * from games 
        order by time desc limit 50
    ) as last_50_games
where result = 'A wins';
```